# How to get the value of the first td of the table using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a table where in I have binded the values which are coming from the Form.In that form I have a primary key Field as TicketId which I have kept as hidden in the form and while inserting it into the table I am showing it.For Binding the data I have used Knockout.So I want to delete the row that I will select.So while selecting it I should get the id of that row so that I can passed it to the Delete action using ajax.But My problem is that I am not getting that id.So how to do this?
My code:

```
<table id="table2" style="border: double">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Ticket ID</td>
                                    <td>Ticket Type</td>
                                    <td>No of Tickets</td>
                                    <td>Ticket Price</td>
                                    <td>Start Date</td>
                                    <td>End Date</td>
                                    <td>Action</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <!--Iterate through an observableArray using foreach-->
                            <tbody id="ticketid" data-bind="foreach:TicketDatas">
                                <tr  style="border: solid" data-bind="click: $root.getselectedTicket" id="updtr">
                                    <td id="rowid" data-bind="text:TicketId">@*<span data-bind="text:No_Of_Ticket"></span>*@</td>
                                    <td data-bind="text:SelectedTicketType">@*<span data-bind="text:No_Of_Ticket"></span>*@</td>
                                    <td data-bind="text:No_Of_Ticket">@*<span data-bind="text:No_Of_Ticket"></span>*@</td>
                                    <td data-bind="text:Ticket_Price">@*<span data-bind="text:Ticket_Price"></span>*@</td>
                                    <td data-bind="text:Start_Date">@*<span data-bind="text:Start_Date"></span>*@</td>
                                    <td data-bind="text:End_Date">@*<span data-bind="text:End_Date"></span>*@</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button data-bind="click: $root.deleterec">Delete</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
<script type="text/javasript">
 self.deleterec = function () {
                if (confirm('Are you sure to Delete this ticket ??')) {
                    var tickid = $("#table2 tr:eq(0)").attr("id");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { id: tickid },
                        url: "Ticket/DeleteTicket",
                        //data: "{id:" + ko.toJSON(id) + "}",
                        success: function (data) {
                            self.TicketDatas.remove(data);
                            alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
                            //GetTickets();//Refresh the Table
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
                        }
                    });

                }
            };
</script>
```

so just want the solution for this statement if I ask in short

```
var tickid = $("#table2 tr:eq(0)").attr("id");
```

Comment: Try this $("#table2 tr:first").attr("id");

Comment: Shouldn't the TR's in the head be skipped? $("#table2 tbody tr:first").attr("id");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the rest of your code goes, but here's the jQuery parts when you have a reference to the DOM node for the delete link.

I assigned most parts to variable names to be more descriptive here, but you can make this more concise for your use.

```
$('#table2 .delete-link').click(function() {
  var deleteLink = $(this);
  var tableRow = deleteLink.closest('tr');
  var firstCell = tableRow.find('td:first-child');
  var ticketId = firstCell.attr('id');

  // ... Do what you need to do with the ticket ID.

  return false;
});
```

**Additional References:**

- [CSS pseudo-class `:first-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)
- [jQuery `click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [jQuery `closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [jQuery `find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tickid = $("#table2 tr:eq(0)").html();
```

OR

```
var tickid = $("#table2 tr:eq(0)").val();
```

Comment: above things i have tried.while using var tickid = $("#table2 tr:eq(0)").html(); it givesd me "TicketId" but i need the vlaue of it not the string...

Comment: var tickid = $("#table2 tbody tr td:eq(0)").html(); This is right one but now the problem is it giving me always same value i.e "1".I need the id of the row on that i amclicking.